# Multimodal activity generator (SAGA) for SUMO - KeyError while running

Tags: sumo

I am currently in the process of using [SAGA](https://github.com/lcodeca/SUMOActivityGen) to generate a scenario for my OSM file. However, I keep getting the error below.

```
  File "scenarioFromOSM.py", line 398, in <module>
        main(sys.argv[1:])
      File "scenarioFromOSM.py", line 317, in main
        '{}/contributed/saga/defaults/activitygen.json'.format(os.environ['SUMO_TOOLS']),
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 675, in __getitem__
        raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'SUMO_TOOLS'
```

Could anyone help me resolve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to declare it.

export SUMO_TOOLS="$SUMO_HOME"/tools